# Exception Handling individually

Tags: python, exception

So I'm trying to write a function that can check the squares a piece on a chess board can successfully move to,

So far I've written so much of the code but realized I will encounter IndexErrors

```
def legalMoves(piece,fen):
    moveList=[]
    attackList=[]
    x,y=int(piece[1]),int(piece[2])
    i=0
    if piece[0] in 'QqRr':
        while (i<8):
            if fen[x][y + i] == '-' :
                moveList.append([x,y+i])
            if fen[x][y - i] == '-' :
                moveList.append([x,y-i])
            if fen[x + i][y] == '-' :
                moveList.append([x+i,y])
            if fen[x - i][y] == '-' :
                moveList.append([x-i,y])
            i+=1
```

I would like to ignore the if-blocks that encounter an IndexError but continue the rest of the statements in the while loop till it exits. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While in Python it's typically EAFP, this is one case where LBYL is probably appropriate. Though you really don't have to even do that. You know that a queen and a rook are only going to be able to move in a straight line - either on the X or the Y, so you just have to hold one steady and then move across the other options:

```
for x in range(0, 8):
    if fen[x][piece.y] == '-':
        potential_moves.append((x, piece.y))

for y in range(0, 8):
    if fen[piece.x][y] == '-':
        potential_moves.append((piece.x, y))
```

(Though that is actually ignoring some of the rules of chess)

If you *were* in a position where you had potential moves and you wanted to try EAFP you could do something like this:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Point = namedtuple('Point', ('x', 'y'))
potential_moves = []
for x in range(0, 8):
    for y in range(0, 8):
        potential_moves.append(Point(x, y))

for move in potential_moves:
    try:
        if fen[move.x][move.y] == '-':
            move_list.append(move)
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

But that's probably not appropriate for chess :)

Comment: Hmm thanks for the detailed answer, I had attempted that at first, but later thought that I'll need to terminate the loop once it hits a piece that comes in between one of these squares (since after that, it no longer becomes a legal move to jump over a piece), so I thought I'd start off this way and just add clauses since I'll have to append attackList later on.

Comment: What I would do for chess is move in the valid direction until a) I'm at 8 or 0, or b) I've found a piece that blocks my movement. It would look something like `while x < 8 or board[x][piece.y] == '-':`, or `x > 0` for the other direction. But that's technically a different question

Answer (score 0):

put the execution in `try` block and a `continue` in except block

```
try:
    your if conditions
except:
    continue
```

Try it in your code and paste any error your get

Comment: add ony one try with all inside if in it

Comment: It seems to be going in an infinite loop inside the except clause itself.

Comment: Okay fixed it by adding a i+=1 inside the except clause, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue the rest of the statements you have to **pass** the IndexError.

```
try:
   if fen[x][y + i] == '-' :
      moveList.append([x,y+i])
except IndexError:
   pass
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions